# Why we use IP address in sockets?

Tags: ip, tcp, network, security, transport-protocol

When a server want to create a socket, it will use a combination of its IP address and some well-known port, let us say 80.
So, when a segment arrived, both the server IP and port 80 will be used to decide weather a segment goes to that socket or not.

The **question** is why do we need to check the IP address of the server, since the packet (aka datagram) passed the network layer check and was certainly destined for this server. In other words,the network layer will not pass the packet to transport layer if the destination IP is not the server IP, so why do we use the IP address in the socket?

And if a host (a client or a server) created multiple sockets using both its IP and some port numbers, is there any case where the IP could be different in these sockets?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server OSes are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [so] for programming, or on one of the OS-specific SE sites.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, applications can listen on a specific IP address / port, rather than listening for that port on all IPs.  A common use-case is when running different web server software on two different IPs.

This question is probably better-suited to the superuser section of Stack Exchange.  To expand a bit, listening for port 80 on any IP on a system works roughly like this (some technical details omitted):

```
s = socket(...)
bind(s, (80, IN_ADDR))
listen(s, 1)
```

`IN_ADDR` indicates to the OS you want traffic for port 80 regardless of IP address.  However, replace that with a specific IP, e.g. `bind(s, (80, 192.0.2.2))` and your program will receive port 80 traffic destined only for the IP you specified.